# Map multiple Models to single ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-mvc

What is the best practice when I have 2 or more models, and I would like to use the properties of all those models in a form?

```
namespace TestApplication.Models
{
  public class Parent
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
  }
}

namespace TestApplication.Models
{
  public class Student
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public char Class { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
  }
}
```

=== I need the resulting ViewModel to be passed into a FormController action to process the form.

=== the form (cshtml file) itself would contain input fields for all the properties of both classes. I would also like to have more than 2 classes in the form.

1. should I use AutoMapper and map both/multiple models into one ViewModel?
   If yes, what would be the best approach to this?
2. should I rather create a common FormClass that would have both Student and Parent classes as properties?
3. is there another/better way?

Comment: Please read the tag info before using it: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-mvc6/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For This I would suggest following solution. I partially agree with your second point.

1. Models should look like this.

   ```
     public class Parent
       {
           public int Id { get; set; }
           public string FirstName { get; set; }
           public string LastName { get; set; }

           public string Street { get; set; }
           public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
           public string City { get; set; }

           public string Email { get; set; }
           public string Mobile { get; set; }
       }

       public class Student
       {
           public int Id { get; set; }
           public string FirstName { get; set; }
           public string LastName { get; set; }
           public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

           public int Grade { get; set; }
           public char Class { get; set; }

           public string Email { get; set; }
           public string Mobile { get; set; }
       }

   public class FormClass  // This is what you suggested but it use other two model
   {
       public Student Student { get; set; }

       public Parent Parent { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. View should use FormClass

   ```
   @model HelloMvc.FormClass

    <form method="post" action="/">
    <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
       @Html.EditorFor(cc=>cc.Parent)
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       @Html.EditorFor(cc=>cc.Student)
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="submit" />
   </div>
   </div>
   </form>
   ```

Note :

3. Controller Should look like this.

   ```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       [HttpGet("/")]
        public IActionResult Index() 
       {
           return View();
       }

       [HttpPost("/")]
       public IActionResult Index(FormClass model) 
      {
       return View(model);
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Though not exactly perfect, dotnetstep's answer comes closest to what I had in mind. And by the way you should use tag helpers :) They're like a billion times cooler than html helpers.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use different names for similar properties. For example for `Email` in `Parent` use `ParentEmail` and for `Student` use `StudentEmail`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you own the presentation layer, I would go with #2 for simplicity and fast to produce/deploy and I don't have to worry about fields that I am sending to the client. If this app is an API, I will go with #1 and use Automapper using Profile to map the view model to your domain classes.